# Python Monkey Patch shutil

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I'm trying to monkey patch shutil.copyfileobj() function, in order to change its default length from 16*1024 to a larger value (128*1024). Internally, other shutil methods like move call the copyfileobj() function, and I want those calls to be affected by the monkey patch as well. This doesn't seem to work:

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfileobjOrig = shutil.copyfileobj

def copyfileobjFast(fsrc, fdst, length=16*1024):
    print('COPYING FILE FAST')
    shutil.copyfileobjOrig(fsrc, fdst, length=128*1024)

shutil.copyfileobj = copyfileobjFast

shutil.move('test.txt', 'testmove.txt')
```

I would expect this to print "COPYING FILE FAST" but it doesn't. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) only performs a copy if the source & destination paths are on different filesystems.  Are they on different filesystems?

Comment: @jwodder, doh! Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

My test case was broken. shutil.move() only performs a copy if the source and destination files are on different devices. Here's an updated version that shows the monkey patch worked:

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfileobjOrig = shutil.copyfileobj

def copyfileobjFast(fsrc, fdst, length=16*1024):
    print('COPYING FILE FAST')
    shutil.copyfileobjOrig(fsrc, fdst, length=128*1024)

shutil.copyfileobj = copyfileobjFast

shutil.move('/dev1/test.txt', '/dev2/testmove.txt')
```